# how to perform fast convolution small patches in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, convolution

I have a large number of 2D image patches and a set of 2D filters. The sizes of them are same. I want to get the filter response (1x1) of an image patch (dxd) when I apply a 2D filter of size dxd.

What is the fast way to do it?

The image patches are stored as a 3D matrix. Size of the patches as well as the filters are 15x15. I tried conv in matlab but seems it is slow. (about 20-30 seconds for 5000 patches).

Can't I do it via some matrix multiplications? Cant I just convert each patch and each filter as a one D vector and do a multiplication?

Comment: Depends firstly on what the size of the patches and filters are. What have you tried so far? You have any ideas of your own?

Comment: A lot of information is lacking for anyone to help you solve this problem.  How are the image patches stored?  Are the image patches discontinuous (i.e. are they samples from your image from various locations)?  How are the 2D filters stored?  What have you tried?  You do realize that convolution requires a weighted sum of coefficients and image pixels over local neighbourhoods, so if you have image patches that do not have locality, then the convolution of these patches combined don't make any sense.

Comment: Is the size of each image patch **smaller** than the 2D filter?

Comment: So you essentially expect a 1 x 1 output per filter response?

Comment: yes. you are correct.

Comment: @user570593 - that's easy.  Give me one moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `conv2`.  That is designed for general 2D signals.  However, given your description, you have 15 x 15 image patches stored in a 3D matrix, as well as a 15 x 15 filter.  `imfilter` is specifically designed to filter images, but this won't help you either because only `full` or `same` outputs are supported.  My guess is that with your use of `conv2`, you are using the `valid` flag so this will reduce to a 1 x 1 output.

What I recommend you do is unroll your image patches so that you create a 2D matrix.  Each patch fits in one column and all of the image patches are concatenated column-wise to create your 2D matrix.  You would also unroll your filter so that it fits into a single column, then use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to achieve the filtering over each patch.

Therefore, do something like this, given that your image patches are stored in `A` and your filter is stored in `K`:

```
B = reshape(A, 15*15, []);
C = sum(bsxfun(@times, B, K(:)), 1);
```

`B` reshapes your 3D matrix into a 2D matrix where each column represents one image patch.  Next, `C` is the output response for each image patch with the filter `K`.  `bsxfun` allows you to take your filter that is unrolled into a column vector, and it replicates the filter for as many columns as there are in `B`.  This results in another 2D matrix which is the same size as `B`, but each column is the **same** (i.e. `K`).  With this matrix, we do an element-wise multiplication, then sum along the rows for the output response of the filter.  Therefore, each element of `C` will give you the response of the image patch for the particular filter of interest.

---

Note that this code is assuming that correlation is performed.  If the 2D filter is symmetric, then convolution is the same as correlation.  However, if you want to do convolution and the filter is not symmetric, you will need to flip in each dimension before applying convolution.  As such, you would have to do this for each of your filters:

```
K = K(end:-1:1, end:-1:1);
```

You would then apply the above two lines of code to achieve your filtering.

---

Because you have multiple filters, what you can do is use a `for` loop that will do the above operation for you for each filter that you have.   You can certainly vectorize it and use a `bsxfun` approach way, but my gut feeling is that this will be slower.  I think it's better if you work on each filter individually, rather than trying to find the response of all filters for each image patch.  Therefore, if your filters were stored in a 3D matrix... we'll call it `K` again, you could do something like this:

```
B = reshape(A, 15*15, []);
num_patches = size(B, 2);
num_filters = size(K, 3);
C = zeros(num_filters, num_patches);

for idx = 1 : num_filters
    filt = K(:,:,idx);
    %filt = filt(end:-1:1, end:-1:1); %// Do this if the filter is not symmetric
    C(idx,:) = sum(bsxfun(@times, B, filt(:)), 1);
end
```

Here, `C` would be a 2D matrix where each **row** denotes the response of each image patch with the particular filter.

Comment: @user570593 - My pleasure!  I've added in some more stuff for the general case of having more than one filter.

Comment: Hm... `sum(bsxfun(@times,..` looks like it could be done with a single matrix multiplication instead... (And what I just learned from a Divakar comment is, that this should be even faster)

Comment: @knedlsepp - Yes it could.  It could actually be done by: `C(idx,:) = (B.'*filt(:)).';` but I'll leave `sum` and `bsxfun` so the OP can get used to those functions.  `bsxfun` is quite powerful.  I also left it to this approach because the algorithm that I described is best described by these two functions.  I'm not sure how good the OP's knowledge is in linear-algebra / matrix-multiplication stuff, but when I have time, I'll update my post to talk about this optimization step.  Thanks!

Comment: @rayryeng: I've done a separate answer to explain the matrix multiplication.

Comment: @knedlsepp - That's great.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way to do this is using the [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) function.

Since the image patch and filter are the same size, and you seem to want a 'valid' convolution, that reduces to simply multiplying corresponding elements (.*) of the image patch and the filter, and summing the result. This can be accomplished via a simple `sum(sum(image_patch.*filter_patch,1),2)`.

Set up some data:

```
numimg  = 1000;
numfilt = 100;
img = rand(15,15,numimg); % 1000 15x15 image patches
filt = rand(15,15,numfilt); % 100 15x15 filters
```

In order to use `blockproc`, we start by flattening out the 3-D image

```
img_flat = reshape(img,15,[]);
```

Define a processing function for blockproc.

```
filter_func = @(block_struct) squeeze( sum(sum(repmat(block_struct.data,1,1,numfilt) .* filt,1),2));
```

Process using `blockproc`.

```
out = blockproc(img_flat,[15 15],filter_func);
```

The result is a `numfilt x numimg` matrix with filter output for every filter on every image patch.

On my machine, this took less than a second to run. If `numfilt` or `numimg` are much larger or so, you could consider turning the `'useParallel'` flag of `blockproc` on.

Answer (score 1):

This is a follow up to @rayryeng's answer. I (mostly) adopt the same notation.

It's possible to apply a single matrix multiplication to solve this problem. The reason this is possible is, that to get the filter response for an image `I` and a filter `F`, we simply have to take the scalar product of `I` and `Fflipped`, where we define `Fflipped = F(end:-1:1,end:-1:1);`. This scalar product can be computed in various ways, e.g. using: `sum(Fflipped(:).*I(:))`, but even simpler  using the matrix multiplication of `transpose(Fflipped(:))*I(:)`. The biggest benefit of this is, that you can compute multiple scalar products at once by just stacking the vectors in the right way:

```
M = [V(:,1).'; V(:,2).'; V(:,3).'; V(:,4).'] * [W(:,1) W(:,2) W(:,3)]
```

will give you the matrix `M(i,j) == dot(V(:,i), W(:,j))` of all the scalar products of combinations of `V(:,i)` and `W(:,j)`.

---

So, first of all we flip all the filters via:

```
K = K(end:-1:1,end:-1:1,:);
```

Then we reshape the 3D-arrays of images and flipped filters to 2D-arrays that will store the data column-wise, as we've already seen.

```
psize = size(A,1); % Patch size
A = reshape(A, psize^2, []); % Images
K = reshape(K, psize^2, []); % Flipped filters
```

Now we tranpose the filters and perform all our scalar products by the use of a single matrix multiplication to get our matrix of responses:

```
C = K.'*A;
```

Which will make for the function:

```
function Responses = getFilterResponses(Images, Filters)
Filters = Filters(end:-1:1,end:-1:1,:); %// Flip filters
psize = size(Images,1); %// Patch size
Images = reshape(Images, psize^2, []); %// Images
Filters = reshape(Filters, psize^2, []); %// Flipped filters
%%// Compute all scalar products via nifty matrix multiplication trick
Responses = Filters.'*Images;
```

For 5000 `15-by-15` filters, this will be approximately 25 times faster than looping through the filters.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what tools you have. As far as I know, there are no batched functions, so you have to do it in the for loop. However, if you have Parallel Computing Toolbox installed, you can use `parfor` instead of `for`, which should improve performance.